# Redux store value set in callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

new to react-redux.I am facing a problem while working with redux store.

Data for store is loaded from API.Flow of my code is as follows:

**app.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import Schema from './components/Schema';
import './styles/bootstrap.css';
import './styles/main.css';

export default class App{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { store: {}};
}
componentWillMount(){
    store(storeObject => {
        this.setState({store: storeObject});
    });
}
render(){
    return <Provider store={ this.state.store }><Schema /></Provider>
 }
}
```

**store/index.js:**

```
export default function(next) {
  getInitialState(function(initialState) { 
    store = createStore(Reducers, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), extension)); 
    console.log(store);//returning  correct store value     
    next(store);
  });
};
```

**main.js:**

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { render } from 'react-dom';
 import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
 import App from './app.js';
 const dom = document.getElementById('root');
 render(
    <AppContainer>
       <App />
    </AppContainer>,
    dom
  );
```

it is giving following error.

[image]

Comment: where/how do you call `getStore`?

Comment: From your description, `getStore` seems to be async. If that is the case, call it when your component will mount and change the `App` component's state when the response comes in.

Comment: @Titus i've updated the question.please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The `store` function which I guess is a reference to the `getStore` function doesn't return anything which means that `App` doesn't return anything hence the exception.

Because `getStore` does an async operation, you'll have to do something like this:

```
export default class App extends Component{

    componentWillMount(){
        store(storeObject => {
            this.setState({store: storeObject});
        });
    }

    render(){
       return <Provider store={ this.state.store }><Schema /></Provider>
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in code console.log(store) is showing correct store value so get store is returning which i've tested in app.js too.and placing your code also giving the same error.by import {App} from 'app.js'. console.log(App) is showing ƒ App() {
        _classCallCheck(this, App);
    }

Comment: @N.A There is no `return` statement or implicit return in your `getStore` function. That function accepts a callback and that is how it communicates the `store` object to the caller.

Comment: m passing value through next(store).isnt it ri8?

Comment: Yes, that is correct but you'll have to use the approach in my answer in order to make it work.

Comment: @N.A it should be just `import App from 'app.js';` because `App` is the default export and logging this variable (`App`) won't show you what will be rendered. React will call this class' `render` function.

Comment: yes i have updated it.edited my question with App usage.still same error.

Comment: @N.A I've edited my answer. I've forgot about `extends Component`.

Comment: I've added constructor as state was undefined there.but it is still giving error as "Failed prop type: The prop `store.subscribe` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`."